# Is there any way to find a word from a list in a string without spaces?

Tags: python, passwords

I'm making a program where the user has to create a password that's at least 8 characters long, contains at least one digit, at least one lowercase letter and at least on upprcase letter. The difficult part is that the password cannot contain any word from the Swedish dictionary. I have stored every word from the dictionary in a text file. Is there anyway I can check if the password contains a word from the list I've made of the dictionary?

```
def main():
    print("Write a password with at least 8 characters", 
          "which contains at least 1 digit,", 
          "\nat least 1 uppercase letter, at least one lowercase character", 
          "and at least 1 special character")
    password = input("The password may not contain any word from the dictionary:")

    if checkAllow(password) == True:
        print("\nYour password is allowed")
    else:
        print("\nYour password is not allowed")
        main()

# This function checks if the password is allowed
def checkAllow(password):
    words = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
    wordlist = words.readlines()

    specialChar = ['!', '@', '#', '¤', '£', '$', '%', '€', '&', '/', '{', '(',
                  '[', ')', ']', '=', '}', '+', '?', '"', '¨', '^', '¨', '*',
                    ',', ';', '.', ':', '-', '_', '<', '>', '|', '§', '½']

    if len(password) >= 8 and any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
        if any(char.isupper() for char in password) and any(char.islower() for char in password):
            if any(char in specialChar for char in password):

# Below I try to check if the password contains a word from the dictionary.
                    if any(word in password for word in wordlist) == False:
                       return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `if substring in longstring:` will tell you if the substring appears anywhere in the long string.

Comment: As an aside , `if boolean_expression == boolean: return boolean` is a classic blunder

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle file objects. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Also, use the set type instead of list to perform the check, it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the newlines from the words in `wordlist`.

```
wordlist = [word.rstrip() for word in words.readlines()]
```

Then your `any()` check should work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can check if the password contains a word from the
>   list I've made of the dictionary?

You can use something like:

```
with open("dictionary.txt") as f:
    wordlist = [word.rstrip() for word in list(f) if word]

if any(word in password for word in wordlist) == False:
    ...
```

---

Notes:

- Checking every-word on a dictionary is cpu intensive and should be avoided
- The dictionary words contained new line characters at the end and that's why the didn't match, you can remove it with `rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at all substrings in the string and check if they are in the dictionary. I would load the dictionary into a set to get quick lookup:

```
def load_dictionary(dict_path):
    word_set = set()
    with open(dict_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word_set.add(word)
    return word_set


def check_substrings(string, word_set):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string)+ 1):
            if string[i:j] in word_set:
                return True
    return False
```

This returns true if the word is in the dictionary.

Also, it's better to access files using `with open('dictionary.txt') as f:`. Then you don't have to worry about closing the file. More info about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)